# How to find WordPress login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm working on a client's website (let's call it www.abc123.com).

This is a WordPress site built by the band's previous web developer. However I can't find where to login to WordPress. abc123.com/wp-admin or abc123.com/wp-login both throw a 404 error.

I can't get hold of the previous developer, but I do have access to the FTP.

Is there any way to find where I can login to the site?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Do you see any plugins in wp-content/plugins that might be relevant? e.g. there [are plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sf-move-login/) to move the login page. (Also: where does the *client* log in?)

Answer (score 0):

Look in your database. Look for a table named wp_options. From there, look for an option named 'ld_login_base'. That is your login base.